# Oralce Apex Data Loading Wizard - The transformation rule failed

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working with Application Express 4.2.6.00.03 and setting up an import app.
I am using CSV file and set correct separators and delimiters.

I need to insert the CSV field with values like `1,987456321` or `0` in the db table field of type `NUMBER(9,2)`. To do so I am trying to set different transformation rule but none is working. If I don't import the CSV field the field is successfully imported.

I set the rule in this way:

Rule Type : PLSQL Expression

Espression1 : `round(:myFiled,2)` or `to_number(:myFiled,'9.99')`

Any help or workaround will be appreciated

**EDIT1**

As stated in the comments I successfully resolve the import of the field.
Querying the database table to check the whole import I notice that ALL field imported as number are without decimal part. e.g. a currency filed with value 159,63 is imported as 15963 despite the "Data Validation" step shows all this fields correctly.

Comment: What happens if you modify column datatype to NUMBER (i.e. no precision nor scale), load data *as is* and - once you're done - round it to two decimal places?

Comment: @Littlefoot : I follow your advice and modify field type to NUMBER. Then I add trigger before insert and update to round the number. But the import success only when I change the rule in order to substr the incoming value from e.g. 1,123698745 to 1,123

Comment: As far as I understood, you fixed it, right? If so, I'm glad you did it. A side note & generally speaking: a database trigger might & will slow things down if you load A LOT of data, because it fires for every row loaded. You'd be better off if you apply rounding after loading is finished, in a *standalone* UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Littlefoot : I completly agree with you. The trigger was just a fast try. I edit my question because after the import I notice another error that involve any number field. I restore all type to NUMBER(9,2) and mantain the Apex Rule (substr...). The import still work but values are incorrect.

Comment: Aha; 159,63 becomes 15963. It seems that you should fix decimal point character. I presume it is set to a dot - change it to a comma.

Comment: Sorry it was implied that I syncronyze the group and decimal separators accordingly with the CSV file